# Filter blur CSS into internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I want to make a background image in a div see diffused. For this use the blur filter, but on the internet explorer doesn´t work.

I´ve tried this:

```css
.me-blur {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
  filter: Blur(Strength=20);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.blur(pixelradius=20);
}
```

```html
<div class="me-blur">
</div>
```

Does anyone know how it´s done?

**NOTE:** In Chrome and Mozilla works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using new property please check feasibility. its not supported with IE.

[Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=filter)